# Get name of prototype object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, prototype

**This question just got upvoted so can update question with what I did**

I solved it by iterating over the window object (or user specified object root) and when I found the correct instance I backtracked and got the name from the index. The final solution can be found here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

**Update end**

I'm planning on writing a convention over configuration template source engine for KnockoutJS / MVC.
I'm started with a little client side POC and ran into a show stopper right away

My plan is use this syntax or something similar

```
MyApp.EditCustomersViewModel = function() {
   ko.templates.loadView(this);
};
```

When doing this it will check the tamplate cache or fetch the templates from server using the object name as key.
The problem is I cant get the name of the prototype object, i tried this

```
Object.prototype.getName = function() {
   var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
   var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
   return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};
```

If works for objects defined like this

```
function MyClass() { 
}
```

If you add a prototype to the above object it will not work, or if you define it like this

```
MyApp = {};
MyApp.MyClass = function() {
};
```

Prototype and scoping is two musts so this is a showstopper, any ideas?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aRWLA/

**edit:** The background for this is like this.

On the server you have structure like this

- Templates\ [ViewName]\index.html
- Templates\ [ViewName]\sub-model-template.html

on the client you will do

```
MyApp.EditCustomersViewModel = function() {
   ko.templates.loadView(this);
};
```

which will generate a ajax request with the objects name as key, which will fetch all the templates for the view in question

Comment: Only hoisted functions (`function someFunc()`) have a retrievable name. Assigned functions do not, because you are not technically naming the function but creating an anonymous function and assigning a reference to it (in the memory) to a named variable. So it's the var, not the function, that is named. I've long expected browser vendors to build around this such that the names of assigned functions became retrievable, but no joy yet AFAIK. Is there any reason you need to get specifically the *name*, rather than the objet itself?

Comment: nooo :/ Yes, i need the name becuase the framework im planning to create will take a object, and then ask the server for Knockout templates using the name of the object.

Comment: @Utkanos If you make your comment into a answer then I can mark it as answer, thanks

Comment: Yes ... but in DevTools console an object created using new will show the constructor's name ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only hoisted functions (`function someFunc() {`) have a retrievable name.

Assigned functions do not, because you are not technically naming the function but creating an anonymous function and assigning a reference to it (in the memory) to a named variable.

So it's the var, not the function, that is named.

This makes the very idea of retrieving function names pretty much a none-starter, since in any vaguely mature pattern you'll be writing methods, not hoisted functions - and methods of course are assigned functions.

Named expressions (see other answers) are a partial workaround but these have other issues - not least lack of support in older IEs.

(Sidenote: I've long expected browser vendors to build around this such that the names of assigned functions became retrievable, but no joy yet AFAIK.)

Comment: Named expressions do work with prototype, but in IE the class will be global, it can introduce bugs and also problems with minifying scripts etc. And in my case I cant relay on that the user has used Named expressions declaretion, so I cant use the class name as key, sadly :/

Answer (score 2):

I think you problem in improper replacing function prototype: if you replace function prototype object then you must preserve `constructor` member in prototype:

```
function Test1() {
}
Test1.prototype={
  constructor: Test1
};

MyApp={};
MyApp.MyClass=function MyClass(){
};
MyApp.MyClass.prototype={
  constructor: MyApp.MyClass
};
```

Your example: http://jsfiddle.net/aRWLA/1/

Modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/aRWLA/2/

Comment: I thought about writing a different answer, but I think this one covers it pretty well. When you do `class.prototype = {};`, you're explicitly clearing the prototype. This thing should be obvious, when you replace a variable by something else, there's no way of finding what was there before, unless you keep track of it, just as Andrew here did. I think this should cover the question pretty well. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **named function expressions**:

```
MyApp.MyClass = function MyClass() { ... };
```

But note that (suprise) they don't work correctly in all versions of IE.

See: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: I don't blame IE.....it is quite ambiguous. Consider: `window['test'] = function test(){};`

Answer (score 1):

### THIS DOES NOT ANSWER THE QUESTION

*However, the code might be useful to other people, so I'm leaving it here, just in case. I don't expect upvotes, but please don't abuse it for downvoting either. Thanks.*

---

I don't know your use case, as such I think you've got a design issue - the problem you describe shouldn't happen in practice.

But let's say you do need to have this working. An easy way to do what you need would be something like:

```
function findNamed(obj, fn){
    for(var p in obj)
        if(obj[p] === fn)
            return p;
    return false;
}

var m = {};
m.MyClass = function() {};

console.log(findNamed(m, m.MyClass));
```

Of course, the solution could be made into a more appropriate OOP form, but this is just to give an idea.

To replicate your use case, it would look like:

```
m.MyClass = function() {
    findNamed(this, arguments.callee);
};
```

---

**So, the final code is:**

```
Object.prototype.getNameOfCall = function(fn) {
    for(var p in this)
        if(this[p] === fn)
            return p;
    throw "Callback not in object.";
};

var m = {};
m.MyClass = function() {
    console.log(this.getNameOfCall(arguments.callee)); // MyClass
};

m.MyClass(); // test it out
```

Comment: Please elaborate, I dont follow you, will edit my question with details why i want to do this in the next few minutes

Comment: @Anders Give it a look now, especially the last code block (it works, by the way - tested in web browser console).

Comment: Just released that I cant to it from the constructor, I't needs to be done from a model Loader helper class, your solution requires that its called from the constructor of the object you want the name for. I could offcourse work around it I guess

Comment: Can yuo use this somehow from outside the constructor? thanks

Comment: Ah, you have totaly miss understood the question. This is about prototype declarion, you just call a method.. you need to do new m.MyClass() and that breaks your code, sorry

Comment: Well then, why didn't you say so? My code might still work if you change it accordingly, let me see myself first...